# Picking Up of points from the Bounding Box using PCL 1.6.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, point-cloud-library

I am having a cloud data of plate which is twisted and not a flat plate, and it has some clusters on that by using the Euclidean Cluster Extraction I have extracted all the clusters and saved them to a separate PCD file, at the time of Extraction of the cluster I am able to save only the boundaries and rest of the feature file are not extracted.

For the extraction of the left out features I am doing PCA and getting the Min and Max values in the cluster and able to draw the bounding box as in the below image.
[BoundingBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaB0I.jpg)

Now I am building the Conditional Filter with the Min and Max values of the given cluster and trying to extract the points inside the box, but when I am extrcating features inside the box I am getting only few points, as shown in the below image.
[ExtrcatedFeatures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1wrU.jpg)

**Note:** For better understanding I made the points a bit dark.

Can anybody suggest me on how to extract all the features in the given bounding box.

For Reference I have also added the code that I am using for the features extraction using Conditional filter.

```
int BoundingBox()
{
 // your point cloud
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr point_cloud_ptr (new   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> ());
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_filtered (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> ());
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr Full_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> ());
 pcl::PCDReader reader, reader_fullcloud;
 pcl::PCDWriter writer;
 std::stringstream ss;
 pcl::PointIndices::Ptr fInliers_part_cloud (new pcl::PointIndices); 

 //For testing I hav been using the extracted clusters separetly
 reader.read("cloud_cluster_1.pcd", *point_cloud_ptr);
 reader.read("pcd_feature.pcd", *Full_cloud);

 // compute principal direction
 Eigen::Vector4f centroid;
 pcl::compute3DCentroid(*point_cloud_ptr, centroid);
 Eigen::Matrix3f covariance;
 computeCovarianceMatrixNormalized(*point_cloud_ptr, centroid, covariance);
 Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3f> eigen_solver(covariance, Eigen::ComputeEigenvectors);
 Eigen::Matrix3f eigDx = eigen_solver.eigenvectors();
 eigDx.col(2) = eigDx.col(0).cross(eigDx.col(1));

 // move the points to the that reference frame
 Eigen::Matrix4f p2w(Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity());
 p2w.block<3,3>(0,0) = eigDx.transpose();
 p2w.block<3,1>(0,3) = -1.f * (p2w.block<3,3>(0,0) * centroid.head<3>());
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cPoints;
 pcl::transformPointCloud(*point_cloud_ptr, cPoints, p2w);

 pcl::PointXYZ min_pt, max_pt;
 pcl::getMinMax3D(cPoints, min_pt, max_pt);
 const Eigen::Vector3f mean_diag = 0.5f*(max_pt.getVector3fMap() + min_pt.getVector3fMap());

 // final transform
 const Eigen::Quaternionf qfinal(eigDx);
 const Eigen::Vector3f tfinal = eigDx*mean_diag + centroid.head<3>();

 // draw the cloud and the box
 pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer;
 viewer.addPointCloud(Full_cloud);
 viewer.addCube(tfinal, qfinal, max_pt.x - min_pt.x, max_pt.y - min_pt.y, max_pt.z - min_pt.z);
 viewer.spin();

 pcl::ConditionAnd<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr range_cond (new 
    pcl::ConditionAnd<pcl::PointXYZ> ()); 
 range_cond->addComparison (pcl::FieldComparison<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr (new 
     pcl::FieldComparison<pcl::PointXYZ> ("x", pcl::ComparisonOps::GT, min_pt.x))); 
range_cond->addComparison (pcl::FieldComparison<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr (new 
     pcl::FieldComparison<pcl::PointXYZ> ("x", pcl::ComparisonOps::LT, max_pt.x))); 
 range_cond->addComparison (pcl::FieldComparison<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr (new 
    pcl::FieldComparison<pcl::PointXYZ> ("y", pcl::ComparisonOps::GT, min_pt.y))); 
 range_cond->addComparison (pcl::FieldComparison<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr (new 
    pcl::FieldComparison<pcl::PointXYZ> ("y", pcl::ComparisonOps::LT, max_pt.y))); 
 range_cond->addComparison (pcl::FieldComparison<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr (new 
    pcl::FieldComparison<pcl::PointXYZ> ("z", pcl::ComparisonOps::GT, min_pt.z))); 
 range_cond->addComparison (pcl::FieldComparison<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr (new 
    pcl::FieldComparison<pcl::PointXYZ> ("z", pcl::ComparisonOps::LT, max_pt.z))); 
 // build the filter 
 pcl::ConditionalRemoval<pcl::PointXYZ> condrem; 
 condrem.setCondition (range_cond); 
 condrem.setInputCloud (Full_cloud); 
 // apply filter 
 condrem.filter (*cloud_filtered);

 ss << "Filtered_Cloud.pcd";
 writer.write<pcl::PointXYZ> (ss.str (), *cloud_filtered, false); 

 return(0);
```

}

I am using PCL 1.6.0, Win 7 and Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks In adavnce any suggestion wil be helpful

Comment: Your best bet is probably to remove all the conditions except one and check the points that are being removed. That would give you a clue about what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion but I have got the solution. The mistake that I was doing was that for my calculation i used to transform the cluster cloud and i used to overlap those extracted clusters on a normal cloud, nw i have applied the transformation to the full cloud also that made the difference, now I am able extract the full features and clusters.